# @SVGR cannot open assembly

Tags: reactjs, svg

I am using SVGR to convert my SVG files to components in a react web app. I used this command several times in this project a  month ago but it throws an error now, however, I didn't change any folding structure or whatsoever.

here is the command I use(convert all svg files from svg folder to icons folder):

```
npx @svgr/cli src/assets/images/svg --out-dir src/components/icons --icon --replace-attr-values "#000=currentColor"
```

and here is the error:

Cannot open assembly 'src/assets/images/svg': File does not contain a valid CIL image.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! Instead of using that command I added this line to my package.json in scripts section:

```
svgr -d src/components/icons/ src/assets/images/svg --replace-attr-values '#000=currentColor'
```

and easily run

```
npm run svgr
```

and the job is done and icon components are made in src/components/icons/ directory.